# Create text field with keyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Is there any way to make a text field with keyboard (such as Twitter or Whatsapp)?

I tried to find some help from Google but I could not.

[image: Text field with keyboard]

Can anyone help me with this issue or at least to direct me where I can find some info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`UITextField`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html) for the text, but I assume your problem is with getting the field to rise with the keyboard when the user selects it.

This is a bit of a tricky problem, but the general solution is to use a [`UIScrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html) and tell the keyboard to scroll when the user selects the field. This is especially important in iOS 8, which introduces custom keyboards; because third party keyboards can be any height, you can no longer hardcode the default keyboard height to scroll to.

Apple describes how to use this approach under "Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard" in their ["Text Programming Guide for iOS."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)